# PHP show all requests when page is load

Tags: php, dom, request, page-load-time

I am building a script which detects page load time. I can get page overall load time with

```
     $start = microtime(true);
 $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.apple.com/');
 echo "It takes ";
echo microtime(true) - $start . " seconds to load your site" . '<br>';
```

But i want to get load time of each request made to web url. Like this

[image]

This is the result of gmetrix.com on google.com. I want to create the same thing. I tried with simple html dom to get all content from page like images and other stuff, i also get there file size with php filesize function but i couldn't find a way to measure a load time of each file. Is there an way to get all request when page load via php. I dont know its possible with dom script or not, if there is another way please tell. Kindly guide me

Comment: its 24 hours now no reply, please help

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar for verifying sitemap.xml: https://github.com/paul-m/sitemap_verify

It leverages the Goutte framework to do a bunch of the DOM heavy lifting: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

It uses `Goutte\Client` to a) download and parse the XML, and then b) make a HEAD request against each of the resources, and verify it exists.

You could adopt a similar strategy:

- Use `Goutte\Client` to get the contents of the page.
- Scrape it for resources.
- Use `Goutte\Client` to time the download of each resource, or just do a HEAD request and look at Content-Length to make an estimation.